# Easy functions?

Tags: algorithms, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function, and suppose that we want to compute
$f(x)$. The input consists of the digits of $x$ and the output of
a rational number approximating $f(x)$. A function $f$ is called easy if
there is
an algorithm which computes $f(x)$ with accuracy $2^{-n}$
using $n^{1+o(1)}$
arithmetic operations.

It is known that elementary functions like $e^x,\log x$ are easy.

> Is it known (proven) about any reasonable function
>   that it is hard (not easy)?

For an algorithm, using the AGM, showing that $e^x$ is easy, a reference is
D. Newman, Rational approximation versus fast computer methods,
Lectures on approximation and value distribution, pp. 149.174,
Sém. Math. Sup., 79, Presses Univ. Montréal, Montreal, Que., 1982.

EDIT1: The same paper contains a proof that multiplication is easy (fast multiplication), 
and if $f$ is easy then
the inverse function is easy (Newton's method).

EDIT2: I understand that with our present knowledge we cannot compute Euler's constant
efficiently. But I don't know a proof that this is impossible.

Remark. I am mostly interested in analytic functions, even "special functions". Are they all easy?

Comment: I suspect that by "arithmetic operations," you mean operations on the whole input, not operations on individual digits?

Comment: Plus we need an explanation of "reasonable" ... there is a constant function (depending on the Goldbach problem, for example) whose digits cannot be computed in any amount of time as far as we know today...

Comment: My vague suspect is that many "reasonable" functions may be hard, but only "unreasonable" ones allow you to prove it (on that point being curiously reasonable) 

Comment: I guess you actually mean digit operations, otherwise the parameter $n$ doesn't make sense. In that case, the representation is a serious issue and using digits is usually not the best; interval representation is generally much better (e.g., http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13166/addition-of-definable-numbers-decidable/13175#13175 ).

Comment: Francois: by arithmetic operation I mean an operation on one bit.
That addition and multiplication are easy (in the sense I defined)
is known. Instead of "operations" you can count the time needed
to an ordinary computer to compute $f(x)$ to $n$ digits. It makes
no difference.

The question what is "reasonable" function is harder. Choose yourself.
"Goldbach" function is not an example, because I asked for a proof,
that the function is hard.

Comment: All but countably many constants are non-computable, and thus hard.
For one particular provable example, take Chaitin's constant.

Comment: Alexandre, the computation model does make a difference but there is a standard choice for this: multi-tape Turing machine. There is still the issue of representation. The most robust representation system is (dyadic) rational Cauchy sequences with fixed modulus of convergence ($2^{-n}$ is standard but the choice is irrelevant). If you insist on digit representation, that does change the problem a lot.

Comment: Decimal digit representation is **wrong**, as it makes multiplication by 3 non-computable.

Comment: Alexandre, please see the post I linked to in an earlier comment.

Comment: I accept the criticism of Francois and Andrej about "digits" of
the output, and I edited the question accordingly. Hope it is correct now.  

Comment: Robert: thanks for telling us about Chaitin's constant. I was asking about "reasonable" function. (I am an analyst... and atheist:-)

Comment: Do you mean relative or absolute accuracy ? Also can you comment on the following example (from Richard Feynman memories) compute sin(10^10) it seems simple - just take 10^10 mod 2pi , but how to take this mod ? Is it easy in the definition you give ? 

Comment: Or it might be sin(100!) I do not remember for sure...

Comment: @Eremenko: This does not answer your question, but might be an example quite close to what you are interesting in: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.6218

Here, Braverman & Yampolsky show that there is an easy number "c", such that the Julia set of $z^2+cz$ is non-computable.


Comment: Regarding the second edit: it is not even proved that Euler's constant is *not* rational, which (except I confused something) would seem like inevitable to establish any hardness of computation.   

Comment: Alexander: $\sin(100!)$ is easy:-) If $T_0$ is the number of operations to compute the fractional part of $100!/(2\pi)$ and
$T(n)$ the number of operations to compute $\sin x$ for $x\in(0,2\pi)$
then the number of operations required is just $T_0+T(n)$.

Comment: The problem that stumped Feynman was: $\tan 10^{100}$.  He had claimed that he could, in under 60 seconds, estimate the solution to any numerical problem that could be stated in 10 seconds, within 10 percent accuracy.

Answer (score 7):

Any (uniformly) polynomial-time computable function must have a polynomial modulus of (uniform) continuity [Ker-I Ko 1991,Theorem 2.10]. 
The function $0\lt x\mapsto1/\ln(e/x)$ is well-defined on [0;1] and (exponential-time) computable yet has no polynomial modulus of continuity at 0; see Example 1.12 in [arXiv:1211.4974](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4974). 
It is not analytic at 0, though...

For the stronger question on 'simple' real numbers (i.e. constant functions, cmp. Norbert Müller's answer) that are not computable within polynomial space, say, confer [periods in Model Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20430/is-there-an-explicit-example-of-a-complex-number-which-is-not-a-period) and [this article by Tent and Ziegler](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1384).

Comment: What is [Ko91]?

Comment: It is the book I cited in my answer.

Comment: Martin, let me try to clarify your statement that the function is
not analytic. Log IS an easy function, in the sense that it can be
computed with $n^{1+o(1)}$ operations for every $x$. The $o(1)$ may
depend on $x$. The theorem you cite is about polynomial time
uniform in $x$.

Comment: The point, I think, is that $f(0) = 0$ while $f(e^{-n})= 1/(n+1)$; to get $f(x)$ accurate to within $e^{-k}$ you need to be able to tell the difference between $x=0$ and $x=\exp(e^{-k})$, which requires looking at exponentially many digits of $x$.  Of course $f(x)$ is not analytic at $x=0$.  Any function that is Lipschitz on a compact set has a polynomial modulus of continuity.

Answer (score 3):

If we consider constant functions (trivially analytic...), then we could change the original question to: Are there "reasonable" real numbers that are not computable in quadratic time?
As there is a time hierachy theorem on the real numbers (Norbert Th. Müller: Subpolynomial Complexity Classes of Real Functions and Real Numbers. ICALP 1986: 284-293), there exist numbers in qubic time that are not in quadratic time. Whether there numbers are as "reasonable" as $\pi$ or $e$, however, is another question...

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of relevant references. I will try to find one that is specifically about the exponential functions. But in general it is a bit too optimistic to hope for such low complexity as $n^{1 + o(1)}$. You cannot expect it to be faster than multiplication.

- Ker I-Ko, [Complexity theory of real functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=V9hQAAAAMAAJ). Birkhäuser, 1991.
- Klaus Weihrauch, [Computational complexity on computable metric spaces](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2002/014/download/), Mathematical Logic Quarterly, Volume 49, Issue 1, pages 3–21, January 2003

Comment: $\Omega(M(n))$ is a trivial lower bound, where $M(n)$ is complexity of multiplication. I think the OP might be searching for the $O(n^{1+o(1)}M(n)$??

Comment: But multiplication of $n$-digit integers is $n^{1+o(1)}$ using Schönhage–Strassen and similar algorithms.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification Robert.

Comment: I don't disagree with your lack of optimism. However, multiplication is $n^{1+o(1)}$ via FFT. It sounds like you're saying otherwise, but I think it's just a minor error in the way you formulated your statement. Anyway, it's still too optimistic to think that everything can be almost as fast as multiplication.

Comment: Andrej, I did NOT ask anything about the exponential function.

Comment: I am generally confused, please discount my answer.

Comment: Andrej, you can delete your own comment, if you wish, or edit your answer.

Comment: I know, thanks, but I would be less than generally confused if I did that.