# What is known about "anti polynomials"?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I recently encountered a problem whose solution required solving $f(x):=\sum\alpha_i r_i^x\, =\, c;\ \alpha_i,r_i,x\in\mathbb{R},i\in I\subset\mathbb{N}, $ for $x$.

While the Newton method solves the problem satisfactorily from a theoretical point of view, it is expensive to evaluate $f(x)$ repeatedly; therefore my hope is that maybe simpler representations of or approximations to $f(x)$ could be known.

My hope is rooted in the observation that the similar functions $g(x) := \sum\alpha_i i^x$ are polynomials with the role of base and exponent exchanged; lets call these functions anti-polynomials.

> **Question:**
>
> what is known about representations or approximations of anti-polynomials, that allow for faster evaluation with a given error bound?

Comment: Even though it's quite a mouthful, and not as colorful as “anti-polynomials”, I think the phrase “linear combination of exponentials with integer base” should appear somewhere, e.g., in this comment, to provide a more searchable description of what you are referring to.

Comment: $g(x)$ is a Dirichlet series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series and $f(x)$ should be related to general Dirichlet series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series .

Comment: These are also known as [exponential polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_polynomial) (just write $r^x = \exp(x\n r)$. The Wikipedia page has some starting references about them, which includes studying their zeros.

Comment: Calculation of exponentials is not "expensive"; exponential is an "easy function" https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116536/easy-functions

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko while it is true that the evaluation of *an* exponential is not expensive, the evaluation of many of them may degrade performance and it ma be desirable to find an approximation with fewer terms for the bulk work in root-finding and only switch back to the expensive function for the "last mile"

Comment: Manfred Weis: Still this is not a problem: you can always choose a good approximation of the exponential (in desired range) by a rational function.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine your hint to exponential polynomials led to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4427340/355149) that is in the vein of what Ihoped for

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko regarding the cost of evaluating exponentials one must be aware that there are different cost-models and which is chosen for making statements like "cheap" or "expensive"; while it is ok for theoretical discussions to ignore constant factors, they can make a crucial diffrence for the execution time of actual implementations.