Complexity of evaluation of analytic functions
Given an analytic function $f(x)$ (say as combination of elementary functions and operators), is it possible to compute $n$ first bits of the value of the function on the whole interval $[a, b]$ inside the circle of convergence in polynomial time? For example, if the function is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and oscillating if we don't allow to use argument reduction?
What if we restrict on the case of holonomic functions and use van der Hovens method?.

Similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116536/easy-functions?rq=1
